# Определение ошибки в linux ioctl(..)

Tags: c, web-camera, c++, linux

Пытаюсь получить изображение с камеры посредством v4l, ioctl возвращает -1. Как-нибудь можно получить описание ошибки?

Answer (score 4):

Описание ошибки можно получить из errno.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
...
if (ioctl(...) == -1) {
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Другааан :D Сорри за оффтоп :)

Comment: `perror("Error:")` - более короткая запись детализации ошибки в консоле

Answer (score 1):

Только хорошо сначала сохранить значение errno  в какой-либо переменной типа int и уже ее использовать в дальнейшем коде.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
...
if (ioctl(...) == -1) {
    int n = errno;
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(n));
}
```

Все дело в том, что между генерацией ее значения вызовом ioctl и использованием может произойти еще какая-нибудь ошибка и ее значение изменится.

Comment: В данном случае вы не правы, между вызовами ioctl и strerror нет никаких других вызовов, которые могут поменять errno